# NSNumberFormatter's multiplier rounds down instead of showing fraction

Tags: iphone, ios, nsnumberformatter

I have configured an NSNumberFormatter to convert amounts that are stored as cents in an NSDictionary to euro's. Because they're stored as cents, I have set the formatter's `multiplier` to `[NSNumber numberWithDouble:0.01]`. However, when I try to display 304 euro cents as euro's I get `€ 3,00`.

This leads me to believe that the multiplier is doing integer division instead of double division.

**NSFormatter configuration**

```
/** 
 Returns an NSNumberFormatter that can be used to display currency in euro's (as determined in The Netherlands).
 */
+ (NSNumberFormatter *)euroCurrencyFormatter 
{
    static NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = nil;
    @synchronized(self) {
        if (!numberFormatter) {
            numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
            [numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
            [numberFormatter setMultiplier:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:0.01]];
            NSLocale *nlLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"nl_NL"];
            [numberFormatter setLocale:nlLocale];
            [nlLocale release];
        }
    }
    return numberFormatter;
}
```

**Calling the NSFormatter**

```
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[NSNumberFormatter euroCurrencyFormatter] stringFromNumber:[breakdown valueForKey:@"VatAmount"]]; // The VAT amount would be 304.
```

**Result**

`€ 3,00`

How can I stop errounous behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code.

```
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[NSNumberFormatter euroCurrencyFormatter] stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:[[breakdown valueForKey:@"VatAmount"] doubleValue]]]; // The VAT amount would be 304.
```

As if you pass VAT as a integer you will get the number always in int format.

Comment: Found this out myself in the end, but it's completely correct. So thanks! Do you mind elaborating why NSNumber acts as an integer instead of as a generic number when passed an integer? Couldn't figure that part out (also why I was so confused).

Comment: as objective c does not support Auto- Boxing . NSNumber is a pointer representation (Wrapper Class).So before creating the NSNumber objects you need to specify type of value using [NSNumber numberWithType:value];.

Comment: It's not clear to me whether this is the intended behavior for `NSNumberFormatter`. I filed a radar to try to get some clarification: [rdar://16775214](http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=5897585755684864)

Answer (score 0):

See the "Configuring Rounding Behavior" of the [NSNumberFormatter reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Doesn't help me. I can change the `roundingMode`, but I need no rounding at all (304 * 0.01 should not return 3, but 3.04). As an aside, that's the Mac OSX dev guide, which is different from the iOS one (for example, it has an extra `roundingBehaviour` property which is nowhere to be found in iOS)